# iMac OS X 10.6.8, didn't come with any disks...how do I create an install disk

Tags: snow-leopard, windows, imac, bootcamp, dual-boot

I want to do a dual boot with Windows 7 (the eventual goal being Windows 8 but to upgrade I think I need to have a version of Windows on my Mac already).  I meet all of the system requirements and I have the Windows 7 disk.  But it says I also need to have a Mac OS X 10.6 installation disc - which I do not have - it didn't come with the iMac.  How can I precede with installing Windows?

Comment: Did no discs come with the Mac? was it second hand?

Answer (score 2):

You can use software like Parallels or VMWare Fusion to run Windows alongisde/inside OSX. Those options won't require you to have an OSX install disk. They do require you buy that software and have a liscence for Windows 7.

Not dual boot, but I find it more useful.

If you need an OSX 10.6 install disk, Craig's List and EBay have them. It might be easier to just update to 10.7 or 10.8 (if you computer supports it) and use a USB drive to create a Lion/Mountain Lion installer using Lion Disk Maker: http://blog.gete.net/lion-diskmaker-us/

Comment: You can also just install from the Appstore

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an OSX setup disk to install bootcamp. you'll need either a W7 DVD or iso to put into a USB (if using an air or newer MBP).

I have W8 in my MBPr (typing from there right now).

This is what i did:

- Started Bootcamp assistant
- Downloaded Windows Support tools (to get newer drivers for Retina MBP)
- Create w7 USB from iso (already had it from previous MBP 17" install)
- installed W7
- Installed all drivers from Windows Support
- Bought W8 upgrade key
- Downloaded W8 upgrade and put it into USB (all from W8 setup tool)
- Upgraded to W8
- Fixed a problem with the trackpad not working (had to revert to a usb mouse)

The ideal setup for me is to have a working Bootcamp partition that i can access with VMware Fusion (i believe newer parallels can also access and run bootcamp as VMs) from OSX if i need to. A pure VM is not good enough -for what *I* use it for- (Gaming and Visual Studio)

Comment: You did need the install disk if you were running Snow Leopard. With Lion and Mountain Lion, you do not.